# Bind GridViewComboBoxColumn Datasource programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview, gridviewcolumn

On a `WinForms` application with `C#` I'm using `RadGridView` control of `Telerik` company.

One of the columns of this RadGridView is of type `GridViewComboBoxColumn`. I want to give this column a `DataSource` populated at runtime and then set the three important properties of the ComboBox (`DataSource`, `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember`).

*How can I programmatically do this?*

I've tried

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboIBAN = 
    rgvCheques.Columns["clmnIBAN"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
```

But it ends up with the following error

[image: Error message]

Comment: Don't you need `GridViewComboBoxColumn` instead of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` ?

Comment: No @V4Vendetta it's right. I'm using `RadGridView` not `GridView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone for they effort and answers, all the answers were about adding a column to the grid, what I was looking for was to point to (retrieve) the current column and change its properties, such as `DataSource` as the most important one.

The solution I finally came up with is written below, maybe it helps to other people looking for such answer :

```
((GridViewComboBoxColumn)rgvCheques.Columns["IBAN"]).DataSource = 
    lstBankAccounts.Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

GridViewComboBoxColumn displays a set of predefined candidate text values in a drop down list. This column type is typically used to provide a lookup into some set of relatively static values.

To use GridViewComboBoxColumn [**Check this one**](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewcomboboxcolumn.html)

Comment: Thanks @Andy, this tutorial too adds a column to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
GridViewComboBoxColumn CustomColumn= new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
CustomColumn.Name = "CustomColumn";
CustomColumn.HeaderText = "MyHeader";
CustomColumn.DataSource = this.MyBindingSource;
CustomColumn.ValueMember = "CustomID";
CustomColumn.DisplayMember = "CustomName";
CustomColumn.FieldName = "CustomID";
CustomColumn.Width = 200;
this.radGridView1.Columns.Add(CustomColumn);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Kyle I don't want to add the column, I already have it. I want to fill it with a datasource. -1 deserved but not performed :)  
And for the object names use the right casing `customColumn` means an object nad `CustomColumn` means a Class.